# Make Editor Not-Closeable

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a standard E3 editor in the current E4 world:

```
public class ProjectEditor extends EditorPart {
     // implement
}
```

Registered like that:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
   <editor
        class="com.qualitype.gpm.project.rcp.ProjectEditor"
        icon="icons/obj16/project.gif"
        id="com.qualitype.gpm.project.rcp.ProjectEditor"
        name="%view.project" >
   </editor>
</extension>
```

I want that editor to be always open. But a parameter like for the views is missing in the extension point.

Also, for views this would work:

```
public class ProjectPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        final IViewLayout projectLayout = layout.getViewLayout(ProjectEditor.ID);
        projectLayout.setCloseable(false);
    }
}
```

But of course not for editors. Since both editors and view are technically the same thing (workbench parts), it should be possible.

How do I prevent the user from closing my editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the close 'X' on the editor tab by clearing the `MPart` closeable flag. You could do this in the editor's `init` method:

```java
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput editorInput) throws PartInitException
{
  super.init(site, editorInput);

  MPart part = getSite().getService(MPart.class);
  part.setCloseable(false);
```

**But** the 'File > Close' action will still be able to close the editor as it doesn't check the closeable flag and has no concept of un-closeable editors.

Comment: How to do same on e3 ui model ?

Comment: @Raghu This answer is for an e3 editor (but only when using an Eclipse 4.x release).

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. i am using kepler. Here is my code  Object mPart = getSite().getService(MPart.class);
    if (mPart instanceof MPart) {
      MPart part = (MPart) mPart;
      part.setCloseable(false);
    } 
It's executing fine but still i can see close button on editor

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask about problems you are having. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Editors are conceptually not meant to be closeable. They open on a specific resource (or other input) and are meant to be closed at the users will.

If you need a  non-closeable Part, use a view. You can let a view implement ISaveable to have it participate in the save-lifecycle.

Comment: It's not the saving that I need, but stacking of views and editors in the same stack. That's why this part is an editor.

Comment: Why would you want to mix editors and views? The concepts of editors and views are fundamentally different and afaik they can't be stacked in, at least not in e3. Can you provide some context?

Comment: E4 lumps views and editors together, so they can't be that different. And the customer doesn't understand the difference either (and that's the reason I need to stack editors and views).

Comment: Just because E4 does something doesn't necessarily mean it is a good idea ;-) If you are developing an RCP application, you can hide/disable the editor are and redefine a 'view area' instead. In case you a re developing IDE plug-ins, you should try to stick to the differentiation between editors and view. Again, it is difficult to give advice to without more context. See also: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-UI-Workbench/workbench.html and https://eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html